# Why is the inductance of ionized air similar to inductance of wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, lightning

Why is inductance of wire which is about 1 microHenry per meter similar to the inductance of air broken down by lightning (where the high voltage of a lightning strike breaks air down and it becomes a conductor)?

Is it just a coincidence or is there any relationship?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. This post asks for the inductance of ionized air and the inductance of a wire. Focus on one of them, and offer some information about what you already know, what resources you have already consulted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A lightning bolt is just like a wire.  (In the approximation that the lightning channel is a straight conductor.) Same capacitance, same inductance. It is about the relation between the potential and current in the conductor to the magnetic and electric fields around it.